# Кодировка в БД postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Как можно видеть на фото русские данные выводятся не правильно. Я занимаюсь бэкендом 2 дня и даже не знаю как правильно задать вопрос и что прикрепить сюда, так что извините. Бд postgresql. Сервер на fastapi

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смените кодировку консоли. Именно она отображает переданные символы через [censored].

Comment: Большое спасибо! Столько мучился, а оказалось дело в такой мелочи